# How can I use different android.R.layout in the same listView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I can't use different layout in the same listView 
with a default  ArrayAdapter 
like,

[image]

Comment: you are asking about different layouts in different rows?Or something else. Please clear your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Custom List View and in your `getView()` method of your List Adapter you can check for the position using if condition  and inflate the layouts you want.
eg:

```
if(position==2){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout1, null);
}else if(position==5){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout2, null);
}
```

For custom ListView you can check this tutorial:
[Link](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/02/android-listview-adapter-checkbox-item.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom list view.

You have several options, including:

1. Use the same layout and just hide elements you don't want to display.
2. Implement the [view holder pattern](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) and use different views.

You can use also a RecyclerView, which I suggest.